# Azure Devops multiline yaml key for if condition

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

When I try to set an if condition on a step using the yaml multiline key functionality, my step is always getting skipped i.e. doesn't show up at all in the pipeline.

If I set it as a condition (with a slight modification), it works fine.

The first scenario doesn't give me any errors, but since the step doesn't exist there is no log of it, not even in the expanded pipelines log file.

I must be overlooking something or don't understand the proper multi line key usage.

Here is the step with the multi line key (this **doesn't work**!):

```
      - ? ${{ if and(
                  eq(parameters.pushPackage, true), 
                  or(
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test1/'), 
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test2/'), 
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test3/'), 
                    ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
                  )
          ) }}
        : - task: PublishSymbols@2
            displayName: 'Publish Symbols'
            inputs:
              SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb'
              SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'
            condition: succeeded()
```

And here it is using the "condition" attribute (this **works**!):

```
      - task: PublishSymbols@2
        displayName: 'Publish Symbols'
        inputs:
          SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb'
          SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded(),
            eq(${{ parameters.pushPackage }}, true),
            or(
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test1/'),
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test2/'),
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test3/'),
              ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            )
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are using looks syntactically sound to me and worked fine (i.e.: the step was executed successfully) on my end with a few test runs with the following pipeline definition:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: pushPackage
  type: boolean
  default: true

trigger: none 

stages:
- stage: stageA
  jobs:
  - job: jobA
    steps:
      - ? ${{ if and(
                  eq(parameters.pushPackage, true), 
                  or(
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test1/'), 
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test2/'), 
                    startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test3/'), 
                    ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
                  )
          ) }}
        : - script: echo "This is a setp with a conditional expression."
            displayName: Step with conditional expression
            condition: succeeded()
      - script: echo "This is a step with a condition property."
        displayName: Step with condition property
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded(),
            eq(${{ parameters.pushPackage }}, true),
            or(
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test1/'),
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test2/'),
              startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test3/'),
              ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            )
          )
```

[image: Azure DevOps Pipeline results]

If pushPackage is set to true, both steps are executed. If the parameter is set to false, the step with the conditional expression is omitted from the pipeline at "compile" time while the step with the condition property is skipped at runtime.

Since it's not 100% clear from your question I just wanted to add that if you're expecting the step to show up as "Skipped" even if the condition is not met (similarly to your second scenario) then this is not supported. As mentioned above, conditional insertions are evaluated while the pipeline is being "compiled" by completely removing the step from the pipeline definition if the condition is not met, so the output differs from using the "condition" property to skip steps.

Comment: The issue I was experiencing is that when using the same checks in the conditional expression, my task was not executing. And of course since it wasn't executing it wasn't showing up as a step in the pipeline which makes things difficult to troubleshoot. I couldn't figure out why when I moved it to the condition property that it worked perfectly well but inside the expression usage it doesn't. Unfortunately it is still an issue so I will have to troubleshoot some more (although the condition property works perfect for now). Thank you for verifying :)